# Initialize python class only once in webpy

Tags: python, python-2.7, web.py

I am using webpy to host a web service which has two functions which have very heavy-loaded initialization stage, and I'd like to run that only once. 
test_server.py contains the main function for webpy,  test_classA and test_classB contain the main implementation for the two functions.

```
# test_server.py

import web
from test_classA import classA
from test_classB import classB

urls = (
    '/clsa', 'clsa',
    '/clsb', 'clsb',
)

class clsa:
    ca = classA('subtype1')

    def __init__(self):
        self.ca.dosomething('subtype1')

    def POST(self):
        self.ca.doanotherthing()

class clsb:
    cb = classB()

    def POST(self):
        self.cb.dosomething()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
```

---

```
# test_classA.py

class classA():
    print "init class A"
    varA = {}

    def __init__(self, subtype):
        """a very heavy-loaded function that read a lot of data into memory"""
        print "init class A instance, subtype:", subtype

    def dosomething(self, subtype):
        print "class A do something for " + subtype
        self.varA['apple'] = 1

    def doanotherthing(self):
        print "class A do another thing"
        self.varA['orange'] = 2
        print self.varA
```

---

```
# test_classB.py

class classB():
    print "init class B"
    varB = {}

    def __init__(self):
        """a very heavy-loaded function that read a lot of data into memory"""
        print "init class B instance"

    def dosomething(self):
        print "class B do something"
```

---

I use curl to test the application...

```
$ curl localhost:8084/clsb --data-binary "hello"
None$ curl localhost:8084/clsa --data-binary "hello"
None$ curl localhost:8084/clsb --data-binary "hello"
```

---

And I get the following with the curl commands...

```
$ python test_server.py 8084
init class A
init class B
init class A instance, subtype: subtype1
init class B instance
http://0.0.0.0:8084/
init class A instance, subtype: subtype1
init class B instance
class B do something
127.0.0.1:50760 - - [19/Mar/2017 20:03:08] "HTTP/1.1 POST /clsb" - 200 OK
class A do something for subtype1
class A do another thing
{'orange': 2, 'apple': 1}
127.0.0.1:50780 - - [19/Mar/2017 20:03:17] "HTTP/1.1 POST /clsa" - 200 OK
class B do something
127.0.0.1:50786 - - [19/Mar/2017 20:03:32] "HTTP/1.1 POST /clsb" - 200 OK
```

---

My question is, how can I initialize classA and classB only once. i.e., I get the following log only once, either during the first or second curl commands is sent..

```
>>> init class A instance, subtype: subtype1
>>> init class B instance
```

Answer (score 0):

All you want is a [singleton class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). The class which restricts the instantiation of a class to one object.

Python doesn't have a built-in support for singleton class. However, you can mimic it using decorators.

Answer (score 0):

Modules are, effectively, like singletons. Do this:

In test_classA.py add an instantiation of class A:

```
class classA():
    print "init class A"
    varA = {}

    def __init__(self, subtype):
        ...etc...

A = classA()   # <-- Add this
```

Do similar for test_classB.py.

Then, in your test_server.py change your import to pull in the instance, rather than the class:

```
from test_classA import A
from test_classB import B
```

And within your `clsa` and `clsb` do:

```
class clsa:
    ca = A
    ....

class clsb:
    cb = B
    ....
```

That way, the class are initialized once, by the module.